# OPcache interned strings buffer size lower than "opcache.interned_strings_buffer"

Tags: php, opcache

I recognised that the interned strings buffer size, reported by `opcache_get_status()` is always smaller than the assigned value of `opcache.interned_strings_buffer`, returned also by `opcache_get_configuration()`. Using the following small script for comparison:

```php
<?php
$config = opcache_get_configuration();
$status = opcache_get_status(false);
echo '<pre>Assigned interned strings buffer: ' . (( $config['directives']['opcache.interned_strings_buffer'] * 1024**2 )) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Reported interned strings buffer: ' . $status['interned_strings_usage']['buffer_size'];
```

I get the following results, increasing the assigned config value in steps:

```
Assigned interned strings buffer: 4194304
Reported interned strings buffer: 3145304

Assigned interned strings buffer: 5242880
Reported interned strings buffer: 4193880

Assigned interned strings buffer: 7340032
Reported interned strings buffer: 6291032

Assigned interned strings buffer: 8388608
Reported interned strings buffer: 6291032

Assigned interned strings buffer: 12582912
Reported interned strings buffer: 10485336

Assigned interned strings buffer: 13631488
Reported interned strings buffer: 11533912

Assigned interned strings buffer: 14680064
Reported interned strings buffer: 12582488

Assigned interned strings buffer: 15728640
Reported interned strings buffer: 13631064

Assigned interned strings buffer: 16777216
Reported interned strings buffer: 12582488

Assigned interned strings buffer: 17825792
Reported interned strings buffer: 13631064

Assigned interned strings buffer: 18874368
Reported interned strings buffer: 14679640

Assigned interned strings buffer: 20971520
Reported interned strings buffer: 16776792
```

Interesting steps are:

- **7 to 8 MiB**, where resulting buffer size stays the same 6291032 **bytes**
- **15 to 16 MiB**, where the resulting status reports a decreasing value, so that **14 and 16 MiB** assigned buffer leads to the same **12582488** bytes and **15 and 17 MiB** match as well with **13631064** bytes.

Comparing the single MiB steps shows that the reported size is increased by exactly 1 MiB as expected, but when a power of 2 is reached, and internal logic seems to reduce the resulting interned strings buffer size to match quite precisely 75% of the assigned value. For larger values this than means that higher assigned values can lead to a lower buffer size.

The overall OPcache size btw is 128 MiB with plenty of free space during these tests, so an impact of that is basically ruled out.

I observe this on PHP7.3, PHP7.4, PHP8.0 and PHP8.1, the builds shipped by the Debian repository. I guess this is an expected behaviour across all PHP OPcache implementations, as it follows quite some logic, but I couldn't find it documented anywhere and it might cause quite some confusion, at least it did for me.

Another mismatch of the max accelerated files is explained in the PHP documentation (not the assigned value, but the next larger match of a set of prime numbers is used), but for the interned strings buffer, there is no additional explanation: https://www.php.net/manual/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.interned-strings-buffer

**Probably someone can better explain the logic and intention behind this?** If so, we could extend the PHP documentation to cover this case, or request a different logic which does not involve the negative (numerical) impact of higher assigned `opcache.interned_strings_buffer` values.

Answer (score 2):

I have no explanation, but according to [zend_accel_init_shm()](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/7d5a9dd05da714917535571539487720280de839/ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.c#L2828), a given `interned_strings` will always be reduced to a "power of two", with at least 8 MB in size. So `hash_size` and the subsequent `nTableMask` will always have the same value for an `interned_strings` size of

- 1..3
- 4..7
- 8..15
- 16..31
- and so on.

I don't fully understand the context in the code, but just because of the above I suspect that `interned_strings_buffer` should be set to values of 8, 16, 32 MB etc. But be careful: the size of `interned_strings_buffer` is subtracted from `memory_consumption`. 32 MB `interned_strings_buffer` with a 64 MB `memory_consumption` lead to 50% opcache usage, right from the start.

Anyway, a better explanation than [opcache.interned_strings_buffer: The amount of memory used to store interned strings, in megabytes.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.interned-strings-buffer) from php.net would be nice.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and especially linking related parts from the source code. I'm no C coder and don't know the result of `uint32_t hash_size; hash_size = ZCG(accel_directives).interned_strings_buffer * (32 * 1024); hash_size |= (hash_size >> n);`, but at least `opcache_get_status()` reports back values below 8 MiB and intermediate values between powers of 2. As seen, in my tests, the only difference when using a power of 2 is that the reported value is quite precisely 75% of the set value. But probably `opcache_get_status()` is not correct. I think best is to ask upstream.